# Sybase Sql Anywhere Backup

Tags: sybase, sqlanywhere

**Sybase Sql Anywhere:**

When i backup a database while a transaction is stil active and i truncate the transaction log while backuping, what's the outcome?

1. Transaction'd data changes are not in the backup
2. Transaction'd data changes are in the truncated transaction log file

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your [isolation level](http://dcx.sybase.com/1101/en/dbusage_en11/udtisol.html).

Under typical circumstances the transaction would **not** be contained within the backup.

Also, the transaction log will only truncate up to the oldest open transaction.

Comment: So backuping while a transaction is still active may end in a data loss? Which isolation level would be the safest for data integrity? Does pause the "BACKUP DATABASE" command when the isolation level is very high. Thx in advance

Comment: @Martin.Martinsson No, that would not be data loss.  If the backup contained the transaction, but the transaction was rolled back before completing, then you would have data inconsistency.  A change is not part of the database until it's committed, and the backup will only contain committed changes.  The open transaction (assuming it completes/commits) would be part of the next backup.